# Deleting a message in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am a bit confused as to how to delete a message in firebase as it has this unique key `(-Kenu81 etc)`

I call this function:

```
  deleteMessage = (index) => {
    let dltdMsg = rootRef.child('messages/' + this.state.channelValue + '/-KentOtPSifEqogyBi8Y');
    dltdMsg.remove();
  };
```

and it correctly deletes it but I have hardcoded the key. How can I get it to delete the message I want it to without having to hardcode it?

Comment: let key = -KentOtPSifEqogyBi8Y; let dltdMsg = rootRef.child('messages/' + this.state.channelValue + '/' + key'); Or am I missing something?

Comment: yeh that is still hardcoded...

Comment: How else can you specify which node you want to delete?

Comment: well yeh that's what im asking lol

Comment: I don't understand :-). What other way do you think there is? What did you have in mind?

Comment: How are you generating the message keys?